# SQL Trigger Fake Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table and a trigger. Also I have a stored procedure to update the table. The Trigger is worked after the update. When I start the update the table by using stored procedure, trigger starts and there is an infinite loop. To prevent this infinite loop I disable the trigger at the beginning of the procedure and I enable the trigger at the end of the procedure.

I want to make a fake update to fire the trigger after enabling. Is it possible, if yes how can I make a fake update?

Comment: sounds like a bad design to me.. why can't you just put your trigger-code in your stored procedure? or vice versa?

Comment: Actually, you're right but the design made by someone. The project owners wanted me to keep the design. I thought of adding an update to the table with an update after enable the trigger, but I didn't want to break the data integrity. Maybe there is an update phrase that does not update the table but can activate the trigger. Actually, I am searching this.

Comment: what makes the trigger goes into infinite loop in the first place ?

Comment: @Squirrel When I update the 1 row in table , the trigger browses the entire table and when it catches a certain situation, it sends an e-mail to the person concerned. When I update line 2, the same process repeats. I am updating about 60 thousand lines. In each line update, the trigger looks at 60 thousand lines again and sends mail. It looks at 60 thousand lines 60 thousand times. Actually, I disabled the trigger at the beginning of the procedure in order not to do this.

Comment: @simoncare so this mean you are not actually having a infinite loop? since it just do 60 thousand times?

Comment: if so I think the easiest way is when you update your last row, enable the trigger so it only run through one time.

Comment: The trigger will run if you perform an empty (0 rows) update... Seems like we need to see more of your situation. If you are updating 60,000 rows one at a time, seems like something is already wrong.

Comment: The big problem with an idea like "disable the trigger at start, re-enable at end" is that trigger enablement is *global*. It means either a) the trigger also fails to operate for any updates applied in other sessions whilst the stored proc is running or b) you have to ensure that only a single session is working with the database at that time. Neither one is particularly good.

Comment: **Solve the problem!**. Hiding it by disabling the trigger is not the way to write sustainable code.  Triggers should work.  Period.  The logic they need should be in the trigger.  The only possible "infinite loop" would be waiting for a lock on a dependent table -- and that should not be happening within a stored procedure.